# Codeigniter Search box or search form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create a search form in Codeigniter. I created a textbox where the user can input the title and author of the book they want to search. This is my code so far, is my code right or is it not?

Controller:

```
function searchBooks() {
    $postlist['bookSearch'] = $this->view_book_model->getSearchBook($this->input->post('search'));
    $this->load->view('searchbooks.php', $postlist);
}
```

Model:

```
function getSearchBook($searchBook) {
    $select_query = "Select * from books where Title = '.$searchBook.' ";
    $query = $this->db->query($select_query);
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<input type="text" class="searchBox" id="searchBox"> </input>
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btnInput" id="btnInput"> </input>
<br><br>
<?php
echo '<hr>';
echo '<h3> Book List </h3>';
echo '<table id="maintable"  class="table">';
echo '<th> Book ID</th>';
echo '<th> Book Title </th>';
echo '<th> Book Author </th>';
echo '<th> # of Copies </th>';
echo '<th> Available Copy </th>';

foreach($bookSearch as $rows) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$rows->BookID.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->Title.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->Author.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->Qty.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->OnHand.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I use ajax to retrieve the input entered by the user in the search box. The problem is that i don't know how to code my model in terms of searching for the title and author of the book searched by the user.

Comment: in your view, why are you echoing the opening `<table>` and `<th>` tags? you can just insert raw HTML there.  Keep in mind that your views, should have the least amount of PHP as possible.

Comment: Please provide your `AJAX` code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be better if you could use the query builder, [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) :

```
function getSearchBook($searchBook) {
    if(empty($searchBook))
       return array();

    $result = $this->db->like('title', $searchBook)
             ->or_like('author', $searchBook)
             ->get('books');

    return $result->result();
}
```

Comment: i agree with JC in coding it like this. You should always try to use CI's query builder if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not searching by exact book title. you should search with like in sql query. try to change in sql query

```
$select_query = "Select * from books where Title like '%$searchBook%' ";
```

Comment: hi sir Lokesh i did what you said but it is not returning any value. and i did tried to change the ' ' in the $searchbook but it gives me parse error.

Comment: i did it already it is working right now thanks for the help sir :)